# VBA Autofilter with dynamic field column

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I made a code for filter by selected cell value, to create an quick access toolbar icon and make it faster to filter. It worked perfectly when the filter started in column A. But some filters starts in columns B or C... and the value is filtered in another column, jumping the exact same number of blank columns that has no filter. Do you guys know how to fix it? How to get the VBA to return the field number?

```
Sub Filtro_Valor_Célula()
'Filtra a coluna pelo valor da célula selecionada
'


    Valor = ActiveCell.Value

    ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Address).AutoFilter Field:=ActiveCell.Column, Criteria1:=Valor


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having some trouble understanding your problem, but I think that your situation looks like this:

[image]

In this example, if the given code is run we will filter on Column E instead of on Column C.

This is because the selected cell is in Column 3.  But the field that we want to filter isn't the 3rd field in the AutoFilter -- it's the 1st field in the AutoFilter.  It looks like the bit of code `Field:=ActiveCell.Column` isn't doing the right thing for us.

Try this instead:

```
Sub Filtro_Valor_Célula()
'Filtra a coluna pelo valor da célula selecionada
'


    Valor = ActiveCell.Value
    FieldToFilter= ActiveCell.Column - ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Column + 1

    ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Address).AutoFilter Field:=FieldToFilter, Criteria1:=Valor


End Sub
```

Here we take the position of the selected column (ActiveCell.Column) and subtract the column number that our AutoFilter begins in.  We want to start counting from 1 and not zero, so we need to add 1 to the result.

[image]

Hope it helps.